# How to call KONG API (which is running EC2 instance) from node js which is in another EC2 instance?

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, npm, node-modules, kong

I want to call KONG API from node js.
KONG is running in EC2 instance.
So how to start communication between node js and KONG API?

Answer (score 0):

This page https://getkong.org/docs/0.10.x/getting-started/quickstart/ describes how Kong is accessible via various ports. Your Node.js app needs to call Kong on the appropriate IP address and port, depending on what your app is trying to do.